# Bootstrap VueJS Can´t add class

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I can't change the background of the form-control element. If I want to add the class to change the background color:

```
 <input id="phone" class= 'form-control' :class = "validatePhone()?'valid':'not-valid'" v-model="phone" @keyup="validatePhone()" placeholder="Write your phone" />

.valid {
    background: $greenColor;
}

.not-valid {
    background: $redColor;
}
```

But if I remove the form-control class works fine. It also works if I add the background to the id directly even with the form-control element

```
//works

#phone {
 background: $redColor;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `.form-control` may have set a background color already which takes higher priority. try to specify your css selector more like `.form-control.valid` etc

Comment: Thank you Syllz! This solution is better than Eliran´s option? With !important property

Comment: Yes, please do not use `!important` unless you really have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syllz answer:

.form-control may have set a background color already which takes higher priority. try to specify your css selector more like `.form-control.valid` etc

Answer (score 0):

In css in order to overwrite global property you should use `!important`.

```
#phone {
 background: $redColor !important;
}
```

In case you have another `!important` you can use css tree to overwirte property.

```
body #phone {
    background: $redColor !important;
}
```